# Indentation error at line

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I don't understand why I am getting indentation error at line 
for c in range(0,num_labels):
I am using python 3.6 and scipy.
code is as follows:

```
from lrcostfunction import lrcostfunction 
from gradient import gradient
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
def onevsall(X,y,num_labels):
    m = np.size(X,0)
    n = np.size(X,1)
    all_theta = np.zeros((num_labels,n+1))
    X = np.insert(X,0,1,axis = 1)
    for c in range(0, num_labels):
        initial_theta = np.zeros((n+1,))
        theta = 
        optimize.fmin_cg(lrcostfunction,initial_theta,fprime=gradient, args = 
        args)
        np.insert(all_theta,c,theta,axis = 0)
    return all_theta
```

Comment: This code shouldn't produce an indentation error, but `theta = ` is a syntax error. Please make sure to paste your code _exactly_ as you are executing it. I would say "check for tabs!" but Python 3 would produce a different error message.

Comment: Also post the complete stack trace if possible

Comment: You are probably mixing spaces and tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very naive error but very frustating if you don't know.I spent many hours finally found it.Simple - **Don't consider tab equal to shortcut for 4 spaces or  8 spaces!**.Tabs and spaces are treated as different characters just like + and - .If you want to intend with spaces use space throughout otherwise use tabs throughout.**But don't use both**.

Comment: As I said, Python 3 will throw a TabError if you mix tabs and spaces.